# How does water flow up in AFK pools?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In a very basic AFK pool, water flows in a circle, but it appears to flow up, as shown below:
[image: AFK pool]

Why does this happen? Is it a visual glitch, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no glitch. What is happening, is that since the water detects the water block above it, it rises up to try and smooth out the graphics. Here's an example: [image: Water flowing up]

That's literally all it is, the graphics trying to look better by being smooth.

Comment: Pro Tip: Pressing F2 in game will make a screenshot of the game.